# rule that does not run

Tags: clips, expert-system

excuse my English, I'm Spanish.
I have a problem with my expert system computer configurations made in CLIPS.

My rule "preciogamingoc" does not run, I tried a thousand ways but do not work.

I leave the code here.

I dont know how to put it better, sorry for that.

```
;;****TEMPLATES*****

(deftemplate pc
(slot tipo)
(slot oc)
(multislot procesador)
(multislot ram)
(multislot placabase)
(multislot discoduro)
(multislot grafica)
(multislot fuente)
(slot precio))

;;****FUNCTIONS*****

(deffunction pregunta (?pregunta $?respuestas-posibles)
   (printout t ?pregunta)
   (bind ?respuesta (read))
   (if (lexemep ?respuesta) 
    then (bind ?respuesta (lowcase ?respuesta)))
   (while (not (member ?respuesta ?respuestas-posibles)) do
      (printout t ?pregunta)
      (bind ?respuesta (read))
      (if (lexemep ?respuesta) 
          then (bind ?respuesta (lowcase ?respuesta))))
   ?respuesta)

(deffunction sino (?pregunta)
   (bind ?respuesta (pregunta ?pregunta si no s n))
   (if (or (eq ?respuesta si) (eq ?respuesta s))
       then TRUE 
       else FALSE))

(deffunction tipo (?pregunta)
   (bind ?respuesta (pregunta ?pregunta g d o))
   (switch ?respuesta
        (case g then (return g))
        (case d then (return d))
        (case o then (return o))
        ))


;;******FACTS*******

(deffacts inicia
    (pc))


;;******RULES*******


(defrule tipopc
?A <- (pc (procesador)(ram)(placabase)(discoduro)(grafica)(fuente))
=>
(switch (tipo "Tipo (juegos:g/diseño:d/otros:o)? ")
    (case g then ( modify ?A (tipo g)(oc nose)(procesador "i5 4690_Intel")
    (ram "2x4GB 2133 cl9")
    (placabase "Gigabyte_H97M-HD3 ejemplo")
    (discoduro "1Tb")
    (grafica "GTX 960")
    (fuente "700W+ silver")
    (precio 550)))
    (case d then ( modify ?A (tipo d)(oc nose)(procesador "i7 4790_Intel")
    (ram "2x8GB 2133 cl9")
    (placabase "Gigabyte_H97M-HD3 ejemplo")
    (discoduro "1Tb HDD + 120gb SSD")
    (grafica "kuadro k620")
    (fuente "700W+ silver")
    (precio 700)))
    (case o then ( modify ?A (tipo o)(oc nose)(procesador "i3 6100_Intel")
    (ram "2x4GB 2400 cl12 DDR4")
    (placabase "Msi H110M PRO-VH")
    (discoduro "1Tb")
    (grafica "no incluida")
    (fuente "450W+ bronze")
    (precio 300)))))

(defrule oc
    ?A <- (pc(tipo g)(oc nose))
    =>
    (if (sino "Hará overclock al procesador (si/no)?: ")
    then ( modify ?A (oc si)))
)

(defrule preciogamingoc
?A <- (pc (tipo g) (oc si) (procesador) (ram) (placabase) (discoduro) (grafica) (fuente))
=>
    (printout t "Veo que su sistema será destinado a juegos y que además se le podrá hacer overclock." crlf
    "Ahora debe introducir el presupuesto medio para que podamos darle una configuración mas concreta." crlf
    "Introduzca su presupuesto de referencia(>= 750): ")
    (bind ?precio (read))
    (if (and(>= ?precio 750)(< ?precio 850))
    ;;then ((printout t "bien"crlf))
    then (modify ?A (procesador "i5 4690K_Intel")
    (ram "2x8GB 2133 cl9")
    (placabase "Gigabyte_Z97X gaming 3 ejemplo")
    (discoduro "1Tb")
    (grafica "GTX 970")
    (fuente "700W+ silver")
    (precio 750)))
    ;;(else (if (>= ?precio 850)
    ;;then (modify ?C (procesador "i7 4790K_Intel")
    ;;(ram "2x8GB 2133 cl9")
    ;;(placabase "Gigabyte_Z97X gaming 5 ejemplo")
    ;;(discoduro "1Tb HDD")
    ;;(grafica "GTX 970")
    ;;(fuente "700W+ silver")
    ;(precio 850))))
)


;;*******MAIN*******

(defrule inicio
  (declare (salience 1))
  =>
  (printout t crlf)
  (printout t "Sistema Experto de Configuracion de Ordenadores")
  (printout t crlf crlf))

  (defrule presupuesto
   (declare (salience -1))
   (pc (procesador ?A)(ram ?F)(placabase ?B)(discoduro ?M)(grafica ?G)(fuente ?P)(precio ?O))
   =>
   (printout t crlf crlf "-.PRESUPUESTO.-" crlf crlf)
   (printout t "PROCESADOR: " ?A crlf)
   (printout t "RAM: " ?F crlf)
   (printout t "PLACA BASE: " ?B crlf)
   (printout t "DISCO DURO:" ?M crlf)
   (printout t "GRAFICA: " ?G crlf)
   (printout t "FUENTE: " ?P crlf crlf)
   (printout t "PRECIO: " ?O crlf)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

The preciogamingoc rule matches a pc fact, so you can run the program, check to see which rules execute, and examine the pc fact to see which values have been assigned to it:

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (watch rules)
CLIPS> (run)
FIRE    1 inicio: *

Sistema Experto de Configuracion de Ordenadores

FIRE    2 tipopc: f-1
Tipo (juegos:g/diseño:d/otros:o)? g
FIRE    3 oc: f-2
Hará overclock al procesador (si/no)?: si
FIRE    4 presupuesto: f-3


-.PRESUPUESTO.-

PROCESADOR: i5 4690_Intel
RAM: 2x4GB 2133 cl9
PLACA BASE: Gigabyte_H97M-HD3 ejemplo
DISCO DURO:1Tb
GRAFICA: GTX 960
FUENTE: 700W+ silver

PRECIO: 550
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-3     (pc (tipo g) (oc si) (procesador "i5 4690_Intel") (ram "2x4GB 2133 cl9") (placabase "Gigabyte_H97M-HD3 ejemplo") (discoduro "1Tb") (grafica "GTX 960") (fuente "700W+ silver") (precio 550))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS> (ppfact 3)
(pc 
   (tipo g) 
   (oc si) 
   (procesador "i5 4690_Intel") 
   (ram "2x4GB 2133 cl9") 
   (placabase "Gigabyte_H97M-HD3 ejemplo") 
   (discoduro "1Tb") 
   (grafica "GTX 960") 
   (fuente "700W+ silver") 
   (precio 550))
CLIPS>
```

The pattern from the preciogamingoc rule is:

```
?A <- (pc (tipo g) 
          (oc si) 
          (procesador) 
          (ram) 
          (placabase) 
          (discoduro) 
          (grafica) 
          (fuente))
```

The fact values for the tipo and oc slots match the pattern, but the values for the processor, ram, placabase, discoduro, grafica, and fuente slots do not. These slots can have zero or more values. The fact has a single value for each, but your pattern specifies that each of these slots be empty so the pattern is not matched.

You need to either remove these slots from the pattern or check for specific values. You also need to prevent the rule from executing again once the pc fact has been modified in the actions of the rule (perhaps by changing the value of oc to si-actualizado to indicate the rule has been applied):

```
(defrule preciogamingoc
   ?A <- (pc (tipo g) (oc si))
   =>
   (printout t "Veo que su sistema será destinado a juegos y que además se le podrá hacer overclock." crlf
               "Ahora debe introducir el presupuesto medio para que podamos darle una configuración mas concreta." crlf
               "Introduzca su presupuesto de referencia(>= 750): ")
   (bind ?precio (read))
   (if (and (>= ?precio 750)(< ?precio 850))
      then 
      (modify ?A (oc si-actualizado)
                 (procesador "i5 4690K_Intel")
                 (ram "2x8GB 2133 cl9")
                 (placabase "Gigabyte_Z97X gaming 3 ejemplo")
                 (discoduro "1Tb")
                 (grafica "GTX 970")
                 (fuente "700W+ silver")
                 (precio 750))))
```